# Reduce the number of Django database calls for a ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have a query on some Django models with a ForeignKey, and I've noticed that it means there are multiple database calls, that perhaps should not be necessary.

This are my models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
class Computer(models.Model):
  model = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
```

My view:

```
results = Computer.objects.filter(model=model)
```

And this is my template:

```
{% for result in results %}
<li class="result">
{{ result.name }} from {{ result.store.name }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Using `django-debug-toolbar` I can see that there is one database call to get the results: `SELECT ••• FROM "mydb_computer"/`, as I'd expect.

But then there are many more database calls (one for each result) to get the store name: `SELECT ••• FROM "mydb_store" WHERE "computer_store"."id" = 27` etc.

Is there some way I can make the store name a property of the item, to avoid these multiple database calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) should do what you want it to:

```
results = Computer.objects.filter(model=model).select_related('store')
```